# Parse html table to listview android with JSoup

Tags: android, html, listview, jsoup, android-arrayadapter

I am working on a project on my own. I run into a problem, I hope some of you guys would like to help me. I would like to parse a html table from a certain site to an android listview. I have already some code, but unfortunately I don't see the table data in my listview. So something is going wrong. I hope you can help me.

I know that a call the right data, because when I put the code in safari console I will get a result with table I chose. So I think the doc.select(); is right.

The problem is unfortunately still not solved, because I get a NetworkOnMainThreadException. I know I have to do something with Async. I looked on more websites, but I couldn't find a good explanation about Async. If someone would help me it would be appreciated.

This is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_clubkampioenschappen_singleen_dubbel);
    this.setTitle("Clubkampioenschappen Single en Dubbel");

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    Document doc = null;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect("https://tennisnaarden.planmysport.com/portal/page/pmsportal30/TVNaarden/Toernooien/Clubtoernooi").get();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Elements elements = doc.select("#pcnt1383_8158836_1383_4326089_4326089 td:first-child");

    //list.add("Onderdelen");

    for(int i=0;i<elements.size();i++)
    {

        list.add(elements.get(i).text());
        System.out.println(elements.get(i).text());

    }

    ListAdapter OnderdeelAdapater = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    ListView Onderdelen = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Onderdelen);
    Onderdelen.setAdapter(OnderdeelAdapater);
}
```

Comment: If your "try" block fails, you need to return afterwards. Instead, you try reading from **doc** with a "select" statement, but if "try" fails, **doc** will be NULL, and you will have another error.

Answer (score 0):

We should have the HTML to have more information if the select is correct.
It seems to me that you don't select correctly the html tag.
You should try to find an attribute on td so that you can pick them only.
For example if the topic is a css class you can select it in this way:

```
Elements topicList = doc.select("h2.topic");
```

Maybe this [link](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/04/parsing-html-in-android-with-jsoup.html) can be helpful for you (it is my post about JSOUP).
Hope it helps you!

Comment: I know that a call the right data, because when I put the code in safari console I will get a result with table I chose. So I think the doc.select(); is right.

Comment: Thank you for your link, but could explain something about the parseURL class. I don't understand it. What is the code doing?

Comment: As you already know there are different ways to parse an html tag:
- using the tag directly
- using the css class
i was suggesting you to look if there is a specific css class n td tag so that you can "capture" just td. In this case you could use
tag.css_class

Comment: The main reason, why I chose this particular code. Is that the website has 2 html tables with the same class. You can look it up. It is the site in my code and then de table called "speelschema" also the table "Planning" has the same class. In this case I only need the table called "Speelschema" the other one is not necessary right now.